# Wrap text in datagrid cell

Tags: asp.net, word-wrap

I have a datagrid include 10 columns,and the eighth column is the template 
column created by asp label .Now I would like to display long text string and wrap the text in this template column .I used the property " itemstyle-wrap=true" in my page ,but 
can not work .

so can any1 tell me how to get it ?

Comment: try by giving the width to be fixed

Comment: dont forget to mark answwer as accpeted if you got the info you want..